# How to serialize bitmapImage using Xml Serialization in Wp7

Tags: security, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization, bitmapimage

I have serialize of bitmapImage using Xml Serialization. It giving error,
   "XML serialization of Uri throws SecurityException"

I have Collection of BitmapImage in Observablecollection. OnDeactivation(Tombstone) I am saving property types of Persistent class. On Saving I used Serailization.

Pls Help me, How to solve this

Comment: Please show what you're doing. Don't just describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest saving to Isolated storage as well.

Here is the approach that I have used:

Utility methods to convert BitmapImage to byte[] and back:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter
{
    public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        if (bitmapImage == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            image.SaveJpeg(stream, image.PixelWidth, image.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static BitmapImage ConvertToImage(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (byteArray == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

You can then store the byte[] to Isolated Storage trivially.  I used a Dictionary like this:

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    public BitmapImage getImageForURL(string URL)
    {
        Dictionary<string, byte[]> imageDictionary = (Dictionary<string, byte[]>)settingsDictionary["imageDictionary"];
        if (imageDictionary != null) 
        {
            byte[] byteArray = null;
            imageDictionary.TryGetValue(URL, out byteArray);
            return ImageConverter.ConvertToImage(byteArray);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setImageForURL(string URL, BitmapImage image)
    {
        Dictionary<string, byte[]> imageDictionary = (Dictionary<string, byte[]>)settingsDictionary["imageDictionary"];
        if (URL != null && image != null) {
            imageDictionary[URL] = ImageConverter.ConvertToBytes(image);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Image to xml? The better way is to save it to Isolated Storage as a file